# Flexible layered ASP.NET frameworks (Digg/Blog/CMS)

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, content-management-system, digg, kigg

For my next web site I would prefer not to write everything from scratch.  At the same time I don't want to be looked to much into a framework.  So I would like something that I can use at all levels.

1. Access the DB (SQL Server) directly (The DB layout should not be much more complex than a self written app)
2. Business logic
3. Interface components (Web parts/Controls) -For example login, most read articles.

For the frontend there should be sample pages that I can easily change.

The app will be a bit like DIGG, but with a different frontend.  There is a framework called 
[KIGG](http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg).  But I dont know much about how it meets my criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Kigg meets most of your criteria - I would start there.  There is now a site built on top of Kigg called http://DotNetShoutout.com which shows you some of what the framework can do.